# Remove sublist after first element appears n times

Tags: python

I have a long nested list. Each sublist contains 2 elements. What I would like to do is iterate over the full list and remove sublists once I've found the first element more than 3 times.

Example:

```
ls = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,2], [2,3], [3,4], [3,5], [3,6], [3,7]]

desired_result = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,2], [2,3], [3,4], [3,5], [3,6]]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.

Comment: Please include what you have tried (you can edit to include some code), and please explain what failed in your attempts.

Comment: Is the input always sorted by the first element?

Answer (score 1):

If the input is sorted by the first element, you could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [islice](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import groupby, islice
from operator import itemgetter

ls = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7]]

result = [e for _, group in groupby(ls, key=itemgetter(0)) for e in islice(group, 3)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

The idea is to group the elements by the first value using `groupby`, and then fetch the first 3 values, if they exist, using `islice`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the shortest answer.

The idea is to count occurrences while you're iterating over `ls`

```
from collections import defaultdict

filtered_ls = []
counter = defaultdict(int)
for l in ls: 
    counter[l[0]] += 1
    if counter[l[0]] > 3:
        continue
    filtered_ls += [l]
print(filtered_ls)
# [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is already sorted, you can use `itertools.groupby` then just keep the first three items from each group

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ls = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,2], [2,3], [3,4], [3,5], [3,6], [3,7]]
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list(g)[:3] for _,g in itertools.groupby(ls, key=lambda i: i[0])))
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
ls = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,2], [2,3], [3,4], [3,5], [3,6], [3,7]]

val_count = dict.fromkeys(set([i[0] for i in ls]), 0)

new_ls = []
for i in ls:
    if val_count[i[0]] < 3:
        val_count[i[0]] += 1 
        new_ls.append(i)

print(new_ls)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) to aggregate by first value in O(*n*) time. Then use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to construct a list of lists.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

dd = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in ls:
    if len(dd[key]) < 3:
        dd[key].append([key, val])

res = list(chain.from_iterable(dd.values()))

print(res)

# [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ghillas BELHADJ answer is good. But you should consider defaultdict for this task. The idea is taken from Raymond Hettinger who suggested to use defaultdict for grouping and counting tasks

```
from collections import defaultdict

def remove_sub_lists(a_list, nth_occurence):
    found = defaultdict(int)
    for sublist in a_list:
        first_index = sublist[0]
        print(first_index)
        found[first_index] += 1
        if found[first_index] <= nth_occurence:
            yield sublist

max_3_times_first_index = list(remove_sub_lists(ls, 3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that doesn't use any modules:

```
countDict = {}

for i in ls:
    if str(i[0]) not in countDict.keys():
        countDict[str(i[0])] = 1
    else:
        countDict[str(i[0])] += 1
        if countDict[str(i[0])] > 3:
            ls.remove(i)
```